# Bash prompt invisible color

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there a way to hide some information in the Bash prompt (`$PS1`), e.g. something like an "invisible color", using ANSI escape sequences.

The method should be universal. It should not use a special invisibility feature of some rare terminal types. The hidden data should remain hidden in e.g. a pure Linux console (`$TERM == linux`) as well.

Comment: what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: @akira the purpose is to include some additional meta information (which will be then get by a logging/parsing system using ttyrpld)

Comment: For some ideas for logging, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945288/saving-current-directory-to-bash-history/960684#960684).

Answer (score 5):

Set the foreground and background colors the same:

```
PS1='\[$(tput setab 0)$(tput setaf 0)\]hello\[$(tput sgr0)\]$ '
```

If your screen background color is different then you'll get a colored bar which will show, but the text will still be invisible. If you're using a mouse, you'll be able to select, copy and paste it and the pasted copy will be visible.

By using `tput` instead of hard-coding the escape codes, this will be portable to different terminal types. You can speed things up, though, if you define variables at the same time you define `PS1` and use them in your prompt. That way, `tput` isn't called multiple times every time a prompt is issued.

```
back=$(tput setab 0)
fore=$(tput setaf 0)
none=$(tput sgr0)
PS1='\[$back$fore\]hello\[$none\]$ '
```

**Edit:**

To make *apparent* zero-width text included in the prompt, just backspace over it. To get the `^?` just press Ctrl-v then backspace.

```
PS1='\[hello ^?^?^?^?^?^?\]$ '
```

To accommodate text of various widths:

```
PS1='This shows\[$(word='This doesn't';bs=${word//?/^?};echo "$word$bs")\]$ '
```

Using a variable would probably defeat your purpose of parsing for meta-data, but I include it for completeness:

```
text='Something to hide'
PS1='This shows\[$(word=$text;bs=${word//?/^?};echo "$word$bs")\]$ '
```

or

```
PS1='This shows\[$(bs=${text//?/^?};echo "$text$bs")\]$ '
```

**Edit 2:**

### For that matter, you could do this:

```
PS1='This shows$(: This is hidden)$ '
```

**Edit 3:**

To make it more dynamic, use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set `PS1`:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1='This shows\$(: '\$data')$ '"
This shows$ data="This is hidden"
This shows$ echo "Prompt: $PS1"
Prompt: This shows$(: This is hidden)$ 
This shows$ data="Top Secret"
This shows$ echo "Prompt: $PS1"
Prompt: This shows$(: Top Secret)$
```

Quoting can be a challenge. If you can avoid having single or double quotes in your data, the `PROMPT_COMMAND` technique will work OK.

Comment: by *invisible*, i meant rather *entirely invisible*, i.e. zero width. but that `tput` is helpul, thanks

Comment: @mykhal: see my edit.

Comment: @mykhal: **See edit 2!**

Comment: @[Dennis Williamson] interesting ideas! however, `$(: TEXT)$` syntax from edit 2 is not usable for this purpose, since the text is hidden completely :) i still hope there exist some less hackish solution

Comment: @mykhal: I'm sorry, the apostrophe is the problem with that example. Try it without. What would you imagine might be less "hackish"?

Comment: @[Dennis Williamson] by hackish, i mean the usage of those backspace chars :) that `$(: ...)` would be perfect, if it worked but it does does not, try recording the tty session using (e.g. `script` utility, then look into resulting `typescript` file) the data do not pass. i can't even find anything on this feature in bash doc

Comment: @mykhal: The $(: ...) technique doesn't show up in the typescript file because `$()` is a command substitution running a `:` command which is a no-op documented as the first command under the "Shell Builtin Commands" section of `man bash`. You can pass it arguments which it does nothing with other than expanding them. Together, it says "run a command that outputs nothing" so there's nothing to see in the typescript file. However, if you do `echo $PS1` at the shell prompt, you'll see the hidden text. The backspace technique *does* show up in the typescript file since something *is* output. ...

Comment: @mykhal (cont):... As you may have discovered if you looked further at `tput` there are all kinds of cursor movement sequences you might be able to use, but ultimately, they are going to be similar to the backspace technique.